# What tools exist to help gathering various software elements into complete software release?

Tags: continuous-integration, release, build, versioning, installation

Our software product is made of many parts. Let's say it's made of a kernel driver part, a user dll, and a GUI software. During development, we're compiling and using all of them at the latest versions, but it's not the same when it comes to the release.

Indeed, the kernel part has to be frozen much earlier than the other. Then, the dll is frozen, to get extensively tested, and last frozen is the GUI. As QA advances, we need to create newer versions of the full release with a fixed GUI, but still using the previously included kernel driver, and dll.

I was wondering if there were a tool that exist, that would manage *what version of each software part is used to create a release?*

This tool would possibly integrate into the tool chain, to build the version of each software selected and gather them into a Windows installer, or Linux packages.

**Edit**: How are we doing now?

As of now, we're using SVN with buildbot as CI tool to Linux/gcc and Windows/VStudio. We're in the mode where the whole repository is branched/tagged as needed. But this hurts and makes release process painful now that there are more and more relatively independent software parts.

We are thinking of changing the repository layout to have several independently branched/tagged projects. This would be a much better fit to the software development and release cycle. But then, we would absolutely need such a tool.

The problem is related to having different pieces of software, each with their own branched/tagged versions, gathered into a full software release.

**Edit**: What is needed.

In the end, I understood what I need is a package manager for Windows. Package manager in the sense of RPM or DEB manager on Linux.

Does anyone know of a package manager on Windows?

Comment: I've seen this handled through version control with appropriate branching, continuous integration tools, and build scripts. What are you currently using to build your system?

Comment: @ThomasOwens: Answered in editing the question.

Comment: Thanks. Let me think about this for a bit. I'll try to answer when I have an answer and a few spare cycles.

Comment: One way I've seen it done before, on a technical level in SVN, is to create a "metarepository" that is just a collection of externals to the different components.  By modifying the externals to point at the correct revision, tag or branch, and then tagging the metarepository too, you have a snapshot of that configuration in SVN.

Answer (score 2):

To handle your source, you definitely want to be branching your components individually.  Binaries are handled via a [package manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system).    Best practices for that are going to vary based on your target operating system.  My company does embedded software, so we manage that with custom scripts we designed.  On Linux, you want to make .deb or .rpm packages.  [Here's](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete) a guide for Ubuntu.  I'm not very familiar with Windows, but [InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm) is a popular choice in software I've installed.

They should all have mechanisms for specifying ranges of versions of dependencies.  You can require an exact version, a certain version or newer, or anything between two versions.  Then you have a "parent" package that has no binaries, but just specifies the versions of the component packages.  That will let you upgrade one component while retaining the binaries for the other components.  If you want to keep it all in one package, there's little reason not to just rebuild the entire thing from source.  If your build scripts are version controlled your binaries will be the same.

Comment: That's really good. Thanks. Now, just imagine that I want to use the precise 'kernel 0.1' *binaries* that were produced for `SR-0.1` into `SR-0.2`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm already producing deb and rpm packages, but the Linux stuff is created after the Windows binaries, and it's the Windows binaries that are extensively tested beforehand. Our difficult point is that the Windows package contains binaries from the source, and documents that can be ready later, after the binary are tested. Hence we have to create new packages with old binaries. A bit complicated, I know.

Answer (score 0):

One tool I've been playing with is [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), it is very interesting in the way it lays out the various lifecycles. You can use not only for java projects but .net as well and there are many plugins out there, as well as good repositories (I am using the one from [sonatype](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the term you're looking for is [Software Configuration Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management). There's a pretty hefty document about it here too: http://www.sei.cmu.edu/reports/87cm004.pdf.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at this, but it seems too wide. For instance SCM includes source control. From what I'm thinking about now, I need something that's behind source control.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing you have is the problem of dependencies between those different parts of the software (like Kernel 1.0, Driver A 1.1 etc.). This will give me the impression you have to think about your build tool if it is capable managing dependencies which doesn't sound like that. So you should take a look to Maven (already mentioned), SCons (I'm not sure) or other tools like Ant in combination with Ivy. You need to define some kind of a baseline which describes which modules in which version work together and can be released. This is meta-information which should be handled by the build tool. You can create something by your own...but i don't recommend to do so.

Answer (score 0):

We have a system where "trunk" is what is in production. We create a branch for the next release, when a developer gets done his changes to for an issue he checks them into our release manager and associates those changed files with that issue number or bug ID.

When we go to build we can hold back all of the changes for a issue buy just not including that issue in our build. When we collapse the branch we can see all of the files that were change but not included in the last build - we exclude them from the collapse.

The other nice part of this system is that it takes all of the SQL scripts and combines them (smartly) into 1 big SQL file that is used to promote the release to Test, QA and then Prod.

More can be found [HERE.](http://www.digitaltools.com/ReleaseManager.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

We used to use use [Buckminster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Buckminster) to manage the integration level of software deployment, sadly this stopped being supported some time ago, and we have now completed our move to using [maven](https://maven.apache.org/).

The rest of my answer has not been touched but is left here for reference.

---

We have various code repositories (internal `git` and `svn` repositories, and references to external libraries and repositories, such as [PyDev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pydev)) and it pulls them all together nicely, deploying only the components that are needed for any given build.

From it's [Tech Overview page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Buckminster_Quick_Tech_Overview):

> Buckminster is a component resolution & materialization framework. Its purpose is to get software components for you and materialize them in a context of choice, typically a workspace or file system. This applies whether you are looking at what's available on your local machine, within your development organization or in the public open source cloud. Buckminster removes ambiguity from component descriptions, enables component sharing and increases productiveness when applied in development, build, assembly and deploy scenarios.
>
> Buckminster is an extensible meta-framework, comprising a component metadata language and a runtime, that can execute either headless or as a plug-in within the Eclipse IDE. Although Buckminster can be used to solve common build, assemble & deploy problems, it is not a build or component management system per se. Buckminster can reuse existing investments in a wide range of build and source management tools - Maven, ANT, CVS, SVN, PDE, etc. - and is designed to place as few restrictions as possible on the services these external tools can provide.

Using *Buckminster* I can deploy, in one step, any major release of our software, along with the specific configuration for any one of my customers.

*Buckminster* also integrates nicely with our [Jenkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) (nee Hudson) continuous integration servers.

Finally, *Buickminster* is making it possible for us to move our primary source repositories from a monolithic `svn` repository to a number of more finely-grained `git` repositories in a safe, managed way. This version, we moved a major component of our software from `svn` into it's own `git` repositor and while there were some re-integration problems, they were manageable.

By making the transition one sub-system at a time, we significantly reduce the risk of breaking the entire system when making the move, and either having to revert to using `svn` or suffering with a broken deployment system until it's fixed.